# wine installation problem of package

Tags: wine

While installing wine I am getting following error message:

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages
>   which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
>   conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
>   installed at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Paste in the full text of the command and message. Don't (attempt to) attach files.

Comment: I was trying to install wine from ubuntu software center and its showing error:"This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."

Comment: Please show us the complete output of the command: 'sudo apt install wine1.6' (if using Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 16.10)

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it.